# Drupal 7: Import images to profile2

Tags: drupal-7, feed

Good afternoon.

I use `profile2` and the `feeds_profile2` to import users from a third-party database (data in the CSV format) User profiles must be different, depending on their role, so using profile2 is the only thing that remains for me.

One of the fields is the image field. I used over 9000 import settings, used different settings of the `feeds_tamper`, but the only thing I get is a message about format mismatch (`Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. Value at profile2(6)->field_logotype:`).

What am I doing wrong? Please, help. And sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Done. I imported my pictures using `feeds_entity_processor`, `feeds_profile2` and `feeds_tamper`.

First I assigned obviously unused UIDs to every user in my CSV file (edited it directly in `LibreOffice Calc`). Then I imported profile content with default profile processor settings (mapped UID in CSV file with UID in profile field as well) without pictures URL field. Then I imported pictures separately with following feeds settings:

1) Feeds importer -> Processor -> Profile entity type - EXPERIMENTAL

2) Processor settings:

Type: desired_profile_type
Do not add new profiles
Do not skip hash check
Plain text
Skip non-existent profiles
Empty label
Empty creation date
Profile owner's ID: 0

3) Mapper settings:

photo_url_column_id -> field_image_field:url
user_manually_assigned_uid_column_id -> pid

4) Tamper settings:

plugin for PID mapper: Other -> Entity Field Query finder -> Entity type: Profile -> Field: UID

Images were updated correctly and profile2 content was updated successfully.